# From a software standpoint how does bluetooth work?

Tags: bluetooth, protocols

I'm trying to develop a wireless transfer system (like bluetooth) from scratch and I wanted to first get an understanding of how Bluetooth worked. So what steps take place from when I click "Turn on bluetooth" on my mac to when I finish sending the PDF to my LG Env Touch?
What software is running (ex. Protocols)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question, and not one that I think can be answered well in this format. I'd suggest digging up some documentation on Bluetooth, like these:

https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/training-resources/white-papers